# (Secure) Random string?

Tags: lua

In Lua, one would usually generate random values, and/or strings by using `math.random` & `math.randomseed`, where `os.time` is used for `math.randomseed`.

This method however has one major weakness; The returned number is always just as random as the current time, **AND** the interval for each random number is *one second*, which is way too long if one needs many random values in a very short time.

This issue is even pointed out by the Lua Users wiki: http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial, and the corresponding RandomStringS receipe: http://lua-users.org/wiki/RandomStrings.

So I've sat down and wrote a different algorithm (if it even can be called that), that generates random numbers by (mis-)using the memory addresses of tables:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
function realrandom(maxlen)
    local tbl = {}
    local num = tonumber(string.sub(tostring(tbl), 8))
    if maxlen ~= nil then
        num = num % maxlen
    end
    return num
end

function string.random(length,pattern)
    local length = length or 11
    local pattern = pattern or '%a%d'
    local rand = ""
    local allchars = ""
    for loop=0, 255 do
        allchars = allchars .. string.char(loop)
    end
    local str=string.gsub(allchars, '[^'..pattern..']','')
    while string.len(rand) ~= length do
        local randidx = realrandom(string.len(str))
        local randbyte = string.byte(str, randidx)
        rand = rand .. string.char(randbyte)
    end

    return rand
end
```

At first, everything seems perfectly random, and I'm sure they are... at least for the current program.

So my question is, how random are these numbers returned by `realrandom` really?

Or is there an even better way to generate random numbers in a shorter interval than one second (which kind of implies that `os.time` shouldn't be used, as explaind above), without relying on external libraries, *AND*, if possible, in an entirely crossplatform manner?

EDIT:
There seems to be a major misunderstanding regarding the way the RNG is seeded; In production code, the call to `math.randomseed()` happens just once, this was just a badly chosen example here.

What I mean by *the random value is only random once per second*, is easily demonstrated by this paste: http://codepad.org/4cDsTpcD

---

As this question will get downvoted regardless my edits, I also cancelled my previously accepted answer - In hope for a better one, even if just better opinions. I understand that issues regarding random values/numbers has been discussed many times before, but I have not found such a question that could be relevant to Lua - Please keep that in mind!

Comment: A quote by Knuth immediately came to my mind… “random numbers should not be generated with a method chosen at random”.

Comment: Note that it is generally a bad style to extend or change standard Lua namespaces. Do not use `string.random`, write your own module.

Comment: What do you get for `string.random(20, 'abcd')`?

Comment: Nothing you are asking here is specific to Lua. Lua's `math.random` is a very thin wrapper around the standard C library's `srand()` and `rand()` with all that implies. If your platform's implementation is poor, so is Lua on your platform. Regardless, several answers here make the important point that invoking a program that uses `math.randomseed(os.time())` more than once in the same second is going to result in identical sequences. Your pasted example at codepad demonstrates the effect.

Comment: To mitigate the more than once per second issue, you must include some information that is different on each invocation. If this is for use by a crypto application, then you are **strongly** encouraged to not invent something yourself. Otherwise, use a crypto library, read a seed from `/dev/random`, use a higher-resolution timer, include the process ID, or do all of the above and hash to get a seed that is distinct for each process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts on the first part of your question:

> So my question is, how random are these numbers returned by `realrandom` really?

Your function is attempting to discover the address of a table by using a quirk of its default implementation of `tostring()`. I don't believe that the string returned by `tostring{}` has a specified format, or that the value included in that string has any documented meaning. In practice, it is derived from the address of *something* related to the specific table, and so distinct tables convert to distinct strings. However, the next version of Lua is free to change that to anything that is convenient. Worse, the format it takes will be highly platform dependent because it appears to use the `%p` format specifier to `sprintf()` which is only specified as being a sensible representation of a pointer.

There's also a much bigger issue. While the address of the nth table created in a process might seem random on your platform, tt might not be random at all. Or it might vary in only a few bits. For example, on my win7 box only a few bits vary, and not very randomly:

```
C:...>for /L %i in (1,1,20) do @ lua -e "print{}"
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0061E5D8
table: 0024E5D8
table: 0049E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0064E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 002FE5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0049E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0024E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
table: 0061E5D8
table: 0042E5D8
```

Other platforms will vary, of course. I'd even expect there to be platforms where the address of the first allocated table is completely deterministic, and hence identical on every run of the program.

In short, the address of an arbitrary object in your process image is not a very good source of randomness.

**Edit:** For completeness, I'd like to add a couple of other thoughts that came to mind over night.

The stock `tostring()` function is supplied by the base library and implemented by the function [`luaB_tostring()`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lbaselib.c.html#luaB_tostring). The relevant bit is this fragment:

```
switch (lua_type(L, 1)) {
  ...
  default:
    lua_pushfstring(L, "%s: %p", luaL_typename(L, 1), lua_topointer(L, 1));
    break;
```

If you really are calling this function, then the end of the string will be an address, represented by standard C `sprintf()` format `%p`, strongly related to the specific table. One observation is that I've seen several distinct implementations for `%p`. Windows MSVCR80.DLL (the version of the C library used by the current release of Lua for Windows) makes it equivalent to `%08X`. My Ubuntu Karmic Koala box appears to make it equivalent to `%#x` which notably drops leading zeros. If you are going to parse out that part of the string, then you should do it in a way that is more flexible in the face of variation of the meaning of `%p`.

Note, also, that doing anything like this in library code may expose you to a couple of surprises.

First, if the table passed to `tostring()` has a metatable that provides the function `__tostring()`, then that function will be called, and the fragment quoted above will never be executed at all. In your case, that issue cannot arise because tables have individual metatables, and you didn't accidentally apply a metatable to your local table.

Second, by the time your module loads, some other module or user-supplied code might have replaced the stock `tostring()` with something else. If the replacement is benign, (such as a [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) wrapper) then it likely doesn't matter to the code as written. However, this would be a source of attack, and is entirely outside the control of your module. That doesn't strike me as a good idea if the goal is some kind of improved security for your random seed material.

Third, you might not be loaded in a stock Lua interpreter at all, and the larger application (Lightroom, WoW, Wireshark, ...) may choose to replace the base library functions with their own implementations. This is a much less likely issue for `tostring()`, but note that the base library's `print()` is a frequent target for replacement or removal in alternate implementations and there are modules ([Lua Lanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/), for one) that break if `print` is not the implementation in the base library.

Comment: Finally, I was already giving up hope... Also, I didn't know that Lua behaved that way on Windows, very interesting.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar, I've added a word or two more on the subject, and some pointers to related knowledge. See my edit....

Answer (score 7):

1. **You should not call seed each time you call random**, you ought to call it only once, on the program initialization (unless you get the seed from somewhere, for example, to replicate some previous "random" behaviour).
2. Standard Lua random generator is of poor quality in the statistical sense (as it is, in fact, standard C random generator), do not use it if you care for that. Use, for example, `lrandom` module (available in LuaRocks).
3. If you need more secure random, read from `/dev/random` on Linux. (I think that Windows should have something along the same lines — but you may need to code something in C to use it.)
4. Relying on table pointer values is a bad idea. Think about alternate Lua implementations, in Java, for example — there is no telling what they would return. (Also, the pointer values may be predictable, and they may be, under certain circumstances the same each time the program is invoked.)
5. If you want finer precision for the seed (and you will want this only if you're **launching the program** more often than once per second), you should use a timer with better resolution. For example, `socket.gettime()` from LuaSocket. Multiply it by some value, since `math.randomseed` is working with integer part only, and `socket.gettime()` returns time in (floating point) seconds.

   ```
   require 'socket'

   math.randomseed(socket.gettime() * 1e6)

   for i = 1, 1e3 do
     print(math.random())
   end
   ```

Comment: `lrandom` is based on the Mersenne Twister, which is not cryptographically secure. See http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/efaq.html

Answer (score 4):

> This method however has one major
>   weakness; The returned number is
>   always just as random as the current
>   time, AND the interval for each random
>   number is one second, which is way too
>   long if one needs many random values
>   in a very short time.

It has those weaknesses only if you implement it incorrectly.

`math.randomseed` is supposed to be called sparingly - usually just once at the beginning of your program, and it usually seeds using `os.time`. Once the seed is set, you can use `math.random` many times, and it will yield random values.

See what happens on this sample:

```
> math.randomseed(1)
> return math.random(), math.random(), math.random()
0.84018771715471    0.39438292681909    0.78309922375861
> math.randomseed(2)
> return math.random(), math.random(), math.random()
0.70097636929759    0.80967634907443    0.088795455214007
> math.randomseed(1)
> return math.random(), math.random(), math.random()
0.84018771715471    0.39438292681909    0.78309922375861
```

When I change the seed from 1 to 2, I get different random results. But when I go back to 1, the "random sequence" is reset. I obtain the same values as before.

`os.time()` returns an ever-increasing number. Using it as a seed is appropriate; then you can invoke `math.random` forever and have different random numbers every time you invoke it.

The only scenario you have to be a bit worried about non-randomness is when your program is supposed to be executed more than once per second. In that case, as the others are saying, the simplest solution is using a clock with higher definition.

In other words:

- Invoke math.randomseed with an appropiate seed (`os.time()` is ok 99% of the cases) at the beginning of your program
- Invoke `math.random` every time you need a random number.

Regards!

Comment: *It has those weaknesses only if you implement it incorrectly.* -1, because it sounds like you misunderstood the question; the seed returned by `time()` or `os.time()` is a second interval, hence why the random value will be only random in a second interval.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: What you keep saying about "second intervals" makes very little sense. Explain to us, please, *why* are you calling `math.randomseed` so often that it matters?

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: as explained in the question, it makes sense when you need random values more often than just once per second.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: Well, sorry, but it still does not make sense. Unless you're omitting some detail, this looks just plain wrong.

Comment: It does make sense. You just deliberately ignore it, which is certainly not my problem. ;-)

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: Please read my answer again. It answers your concern about "The random value will be only random in a second interval".

Answer (score 1):

A few important things come to mind:

- In most other languages you typically only call the random 'seed' function once at the beginning of the program or perhaps at limited times throughout its execution. You generally do not want to call it each time you generate a random number/sequence. If you call it once when the program starts you get around the "once per second" limitation. By calling it each time you may actually end up with less randomness in your results.
- Your realrandom() function seems to rely on a private implementation detail of Lua. What happens in the next major release if this detail changes to always return the same number, or only even numbers, etc.... Just because it works for now is not a strong enough guarantee, especially in the case of wanting a secure RNG.
- When you say "everything seems perfectly random" how are you measuring this performance? We humans are terrible at determining if a sequence is random or not and just looking at a sequence of numbers would be virtually impossible to truly tell if they were random or not. There are many ways to quantify the "randomness" of a series including frequency distribution, autocorrelation, compression, and many more far beyond my understanding.
- If you are writing a true "secure PRNG" for production do not write your own! Investigate and use a library or algorithm by experts who has spent years/decades studying, designing and trying to break it. True secure random number generation is hard.

If you need more info start on the [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) article on Wikipedia and use the references/links there as needed.

Comment: It is true that `seed` shouldn't be called more than once, but even if i'd only call it once, the internal would still be only one second. *When you say "everything seems perfectly random" how are you measuring this performance* - I'm not measuring anything - It's simple logic: The memory address must be unique to the program, since a memory address can only exist once in a program. *Investigate and use a library or algorithm by experts* The former is what I try to avoid, and the latter doesn't exist (yet) for Lua.

Comment: Are you so sure that it does not exist? Tell us, why do you need security, and maybe we will point you to one or more implementation. ;-)

Comment: I said there's no native Lua implemention. There are roughly a billion cryptography related external libraries for Lua, though.

Comment: Why do you want a native implementation? If you need *cryptography* (as opposed to just some strong randomness), you must use existing, proven, bug-free implementation.

Comment: Also, see here, for some insights on RNG in plain Lua: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263731/pseudorandom-number-generator-for-noise

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "internal" or "interval". Setting the seed of a PRNG just tells it where to start the random number series. Time is usually used as a seed as in many cases it gives us a random enough starting point. In 'secure' cases this may not be good enough and a better seed needs to be chosen. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397004/better-seeds-than-time0 for example.